# How can I create an APFS fusion drive in Mojave using my SSD and HD?

Tags: macos, mac, apfs, fusion-drive, mojave

Now that Mojave supports APFS in fusion drives, how can I create a fusion drive from scratch with my SSD and HD?

I have a Mac Mini with an 128 GB SSD and a 1TB HD, already updated to Mojave and using APFS since High Sierra. How do I integrate both in a fusion drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing could be easier with Mojave : just enter the following command at the command prompt

```
diskutil resetfusion
```

The process is done completely automatically. Just take care that the detected hard drives solid state and mechanical are correctly determined before answering Yes.

Sample command output :

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil resetfusion

Internally-located hardware disk devices known to the currently-running macOS:
Rotational                               (disk0)
Solid State                              (disk1)

Volume exported by partitions or storage systems hosted on the above devices:
Macintosh HD                             (disk23)

WARNING: All of the above will be erased
Do you want to continue? (Enter "Yes" to proceed to erase) Yes

Forcing unmount of all volumes on the solid-state (SSD) disk drive
Started on disk1
Finished on disk1
Forcing unmount of all volumes on the rotational (HDD) disk drive
Started on disk0
Finished on disk0
Partitioning the solid-state (SSD) disk drive
Started on disk1
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Finished on disk1
The partition that will become the solid-state Core Storage PV is disk1s2
Partitioning the rotational (HDD) disk drive
Started on disk0
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Finished on disk0
The partition that will become the rotational Core Storage PV is disk0s2
Creating a Core Storage Logical Volume Group
Started
Unmounting disk1s2
Touching partition type on disk1s2
Adding disk1s2 to Logical Volume Group
Unmounting disk0s2
Touching partition type on disk0s2
Adding disk0s2 to Logical Volume Group
Creating Core Storage Logical Volume Group
Switching disk1s2 to Core Storage
Switching disk0s2 to Core Storage
Waiting for Logical Volume Group to appear
Discovered new Logical Volume Group "515C316B-D0E8-4507-AF51-3B7F6F65B74A"
Finished
The new Core Storage LVG is 515C316B-D0E8-4507-AF51-3B7F6F65B74A
Adding a Logical Volume to the Core Storage Logical Volume Group
Started
Waiting for Logical Volume to appear
Formatting file system for Logical Volume
Initialized /dev/rdisk23 as a 571 GB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume with a 49152k journal
Mounting disk
Finished
The new Core Storage LV is 60BD449A-F95B-49D7-B55D-81978D4567FF (disk23)
Confirmed that your new volume "Macintosh HD" (disk23) is a Fusion Drive
Operation successful
```

Comment: The answer needs to say at the start. This is not APFS since APFS containers don't support fusion on Mojave and may or may not on Catalina 10.15 - the rest is the best you can do on the old Core Storage / non APFS containers. Great answer, just needs to address the "this isn't on top of APFS" minor point of clarity.

Comment: According to the man page for Big Sur (macOS 11.6.1), the **resetFusion** option will create an APFS fusion drive.  You will get one APFS container spanning both drive, containing a single APFS volume.  You will then need to install macOS on it and restore your data from a backup (e.g. via Migration assistant)